# Why is POST response printing undefined?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to build a chrome extension and when I get the JSON response from the Flask endpoint it prints correctly in my scipt as `{"rating": 3.5}`. But when I try to access rating using `resp.rating` and `resp["rating"]` they both return undefined. Here is the code in my Flask script

```
import json
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_cors import CORS
from clean import clean_comment
from textblob import TextBlob

app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app)
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'application/json'

@app.route("/predict/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def predict():
    comments = []
    rating = 0
    
    if request.method == "POST":
        comments = request.json["comments"]
    for comment in comments:
        temp = TextBlob(clean_comment(comment)).sentiment.polarity
        print(clean_comment(comment) + ": " + str(temp))
        rating += temp

    if rating > 0:
        rating = (((rating/len(comments) + 1) / 2) * 5) * 1.2
    if rating >= 5:
        rating = 5.0
    print(rating)
    return json.dumps({"rating": str(rating)})
```

Here is how I am accessing it

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.message === "activate_icon") {
        chrome.tabs.query({active:true,windowType:"normal", currentWindow: true}, function(d){
            chrome.pageAction.show(d[0].id);
        })
    }
    if(request.comments) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            headers: {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*"},
            url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict/",
            data: JSON.stringify({'comments': request.comments}),
            success: function(resp) {
                // this is where console.log(resp.rating) and console.log(resp["rating"]) return
                // undefined but console.log(resp) returns the correct output
                chrome.runtime.sendMessage(resp)
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Separate the problem. Either it’s returning the incorrect JSON or it’s being read incorrectly. Only include the _actual_ part in error, showing the _actual_ JSON (or closest point it it) in or out. Using cURL and/or developer tools and/or a mocking server may be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`json.dumps()` is not a valid http response.  I think you want:

```
from flask import Flask, request, Response

return Response(json.dumps({"rating": str(rating)}), mimetype='application/json')
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly. Any idea what `Response` does that converts the data in the correct format?

Answer (score 0):

With newer `flask` version, actually you can return the data as below, without using `jsonify` or `Response`:

```
return {'rating': str(rating)}
```

`Flask` would add right headers for you automaticly.